# Python (Django) error - Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

When I open my website, I see this, 
I created project (mysite) and application (polls)

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^polls/
^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

My files
polls/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
import os
import sys

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

import django

sys.path.append("/home/ukasz/Pulpit/Python/mysite") #Set it to the root of your project
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"
django.setup()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

mysite/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
]
```

I had to add django.setup() and os.environ because I had error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a route in your mysite/urls.py file. Currently,

```
def index(request)
```

works when you hit http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls. You should add

```
url(r'^$', your_view.index, name='index')
```

to your mysite/urls.py to handle the default http://127.0.0.1:8000/.